# Useful Inheritance in Python resp. Alternative for interfaces

Tags: python, inheritance, interface

Hi as far as I see in Python variables are untyped. So now I want to have a baseclass

```
class baseClass:
 def x():
  print "yay"
```

and two subClasses

```
class sub1(baseClass):
 def x(): 
  print "sub1"

class sub2(baseClass):
 def x():
  print "sub2"
```

in other programming languages I can develop against interfaces just like

```
baseClass c = new sub1()
```

so now I can use c as a baseClass with the functionality of sub1 and maybe at runtime I can change it via

```
c = new sub2()
```

Is that possible in python as well?

Comment: Please Capitalize All Class Names.  It's The Accepted Python Style. please do not capitalize variable names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
c = sub1()
c = sub2()
```

But the base class and concept of defining an interface are unnecessary, since python is not statically typed.

EDIT:

To rewrite your code in valid Python:

```
# This space where baseClass was defined intentionally left blank, 
# because it serves no purpose

class Sub1(object):
  def x(self): 
    print "sub1"

class Sub2(object):
  def x(self):
    print "sub2"

c = Sub1()
c = Sub2()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this; however, the syntax to instantiate objects is not "new Class(args)". Simply drop the "new".

Taking a step back, assume you have an object stored in a variable named foo. The compiler will never complain about you doing the following:

```
foo.bar
```

This is true even if there's no way foo can have the property bar. This is because whether foo has an attribute named bar is determined at run time (this is why Python is a [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing) language). If your code has a type problem, you might not find out about it until you actually run it (i.e. runtime).

In Python, interfaces are established purely by convention among developers of the same project. This method of dealing with interfaces is known as [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). I suggest you read up on this subject, since it seems you are new to Python.

PS: Dynamic typing might sound like a bad thing because you don't get compile-time type checking, but the flip side of this is that there is much less boiler plate that you have to write. Theoretically, this makes you much more productive. In my experience, this tends to bear out.

Comment: but I cannot say baseClass c = sub1() my interpreter says invalid syntax

Comment: Xelluloid, that's because of the baseClass part. You should omit that too :)

Comment: ok I see now what is meant by dynamically typed =) I never got in touch with those languages, was my first experience =)

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't really have "variables".  What Python has are names that have objects bound to them.

```
class X(object):
    pass
class Y(object):
    pass
class Z(object):
    pass

a = X  # name "a" bound with class object "X"

print(a is X)  # prints True

a = Y
print(a is Y)  # prints True
b = Y
print(a is b)  # prints True
```

The above code shows binding the name "a" with first one object (the class object defined as "X") and then another object (class object "Y").  Then we bind "b" to class object "Y".  "a" and "b" are then referring to the same object, so the `is` test returns `True`.

Python is strongly typed.  As long as "a" is bound with the class object "Y", the type of "a" is the type of the class object.  For example, if you try to use "a" in a math expression, Python would raise a `TypeError` exception, because "a" would be the wrong class.

```
print(a + 3)  # causes TypeError exception
```

But it is always legal to rebind a name to point to some other object that can have some other type.

```
a = 3
print(a + 3)  # prints 6
```

A good explanation is here: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names